# How can I bypass the activation on my Droid 2 Global?

Tags: custom-roms, motorola-droid-2, activation

I want to put a custom ROM on my D2G, but I think I went about it in the wrong order.

I thought that I had to do a factory reset, but that wound up setting me back. The phone demands that it be activated, but I can't get past that step. I don't want to go back to Verizon with this phone.

How can I get past activation?  I don't want to use the phone on another carrier. I just want access to the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very useful way to bypass the activation on this model of phone.

When you're presented with the activation screen (the little Android), press the following corners of the screen **in this order:**

- Top Left
- Top Right
- Bottom Right
- Bottom Left

You now have the option to completely bypass activation.